# How many days can I work in the U.K. without changing my country of employment?

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, taxes, employment

My spouse has taken a two year assignment in London and I plan to continue my U.S. employment, spending time in both the U.K. and the U.S.

I have a Tier 2 Partner Visa but would like to keep working for my employers U.S. entity and not have to transfer to the U.K. entity.

My spouse is on a two year assignment and we expect that I'll be traveling back and forth. Are there a specific number of days or working days that would trigger a need to transfer?

FYI, my employer has 17 entities, my clients are global and I sell services in North America, Europe and APAC.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you work for a single day in the UK, the rules for HMRC kick in and you will be subject to them. Let's look at their explanation in this fragment...

> Whether you need to pay depends on if you’re classed as ‘resident’ in
>   the UK for tax.
>
> If you’re not UK resident, you won’t have to pay UK tax on your
>   foreign income.
>
> If you’re UK resident, you’ll normally pay tax on your foreign income.
>   But you may not have to if your permanent home (‘domicile’) is abroad.

Source: [Tax on Foreign Income](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/overview)

The determination on whether you are resident or not are too cumbersome to attempt here, but if you are here for two years they will likely class you as a resident for part of your stay.  For sure you will need an NIN.

It is not as dire as it sounds because there is a reciprocity agreement with the US such that nothing will be exposed to double taxation.

It is astonishingly simple to call them and present your circumstances and get a reading.  Call 0300 200 3300.  Try it, it's fun.